# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime - DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

Don't know how to handle this:

- DLL load failed: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen (Swedish for: The required module can not be found)
- Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Currently I can't do anything with tensorflow.

```
(spyder-env2) PS C:\> python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

TRACEBACK:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-
env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tensorflow36\envs\spyder-env2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: From your error: "See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help." Did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be because of Tensorflow requires MSVC 2019 redistributable or Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions or Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits.

There is a workaround either you have to build Tensorflow from source  or use google colaboratory to work.
Use instructions mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) to compile from source.